# Download files with extension .00* using WebClient

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am downloading files from the server, but files that ends with .00* always return file not found, but they are in the server.

For example the client split a big file, so the files would end with .001,.002.003 onwards.

I am using WebClient, and silverlight.

Thanks

Comment: You have a file named `something.00*`?

Comment: For example .001, .002

Comment: Can you download those files with a regular browser?

Comment: If you can't download with a regular program, this is a problem with your web server rather than `WebClient`.

Comment: Regarding the question, in IIS there are certain extensions that is not supported directly. If you split a file using winrar to multiple files, each file would end in .001,.002 for example. That file extension is not valid mime type, so either you configure the IIS to support it or create a handler to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve, instead of directly calling the file path in the server, I added a handler, to download.

I need to do this, cause I don't have direct access to the server configuration.

If I do I need to add the file extension as a valid mime type, else IIS would reject it, causing my problem.